# Why 127.0.0.1/routeToFile/index.html does not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost

I'm building site on localhost address and

```
if(window.location=="127.0.0.1/routeToTheFile/index.html"){
//anything
}
```

is not working. Everything worked properly until I have had the need for if selections in main.js because JavaScript code shouldn't do same things for every page on the site. And this route from if selection is the same route on which I have access to my project so route isn't wrong. So what's wrong with this if selection?

Comment: `window.location` is a full URL, so it will be something like `https://127.0.0.1/routeToTheFile/index.html`

Comment: you can't leave out the `https://` part, since you're doing an exact match with `==`

Comment: For future reference, debugging conditions is very easy. All you need to do is `console.log(window.location)` to see what's output. Then you can see why the `==` condition is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.location includes protocol (it is most likely http:// on localhost). You should add protocol to 127.0.0.1/routeToTheFile/index.html. But the best way will be to use window.location.pathname and write this code:

```
if (window.location.pathname =="/routeToTheFile/index.html"){
  //anything
}
```